# How to trigger auto build in Jenkins via Gitbucket's webhook?

Tags: git, jenkins, auto-build, gitbucket

There is a Java maven project with its source code managed by `Gitbucket`. Having configured a maven item in `jenkins` for the project.

And, now want to trigger auto build in jenkins when gitbucket receive a new commit, according to: https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitbucket

**Here is what I have done:**

- Install jenkins & gitbucket.
- Install plugins for jenkins, include git plugin & `Gitbucket` plugin.
- In githucket, add a webhook of jenkins.
- In jenkins, create a `maven` project, and checked the option `Build when a change is pushed to GitBucket` within `Build Triggers` section.

**Current status:**

- Could build the project in jenkins by hand successfully.
- But, when push a new commit to gitbucket, jenkins can't trigger a new build.
- In gitbucket's webhook config page, when click `test hook`, would get a `403` response.

**Questions:**

- When push from gitbucket to jenkins on commit, what is the mechanism to do authentication? How to config it in details. (*I have googled a while, didn't get a clear working solution*)
- In gitbucket, when create webhook, there is a `security token` field, where should the value from, is that relevant to this task?

Thanks.

Comment: What url do you specify as a webhook url on GitBucket?

Comment: @NaokiTakezoe It's `http://localhost:8282/jenkins/gitbucket-webhook/`, with  `localhost:8282` as jenkins's home.

Comment: If your Jenkins is working at `http://localhost:8282/`, try to set  `http://localhost:8282/gitbucket-webhook/` as a webhook url. Maybe `/jenkins/` is unnecessary.

Comment: @NaokiTakezoe Yes, after changing it to `http://localhost:8282/gitbucket-webhook/`, click `test hook` would return `200`, thanks.

Comment: @NaokiTakezoe Though the `test hook` would get http `200`, but when I push a new commit to gitbucket, the jenkins project didn't trigger a build automatically, while build by hand is ok. I am using `Gitbucket plugin` in jenkins, I already checked `Build when a change is pushed to GitBucket` option for the project, do you know what I am missing?

Comment: @NaokiTakezoe In `gogs` (a similar tool as gitbucket), the webhook is specified as `http://localhost:8282/gogs-webhook/?job=xxx`, so that it knows which jenkins job to trigger, don't know how to specify the job name in gitbucket, didn't found that information in https://plugins.jenkins.io/gitbucket

Comment: Hmm... I tested this plugin with the latest version of GitBucket and it worked fine. This plugin figures out target jobs automatically by comparing repository url in the webhook payload and job. So you have to configure a repository url in your job correctly.

Comment: @NaokiTakezoe About the repository url mentioned in above comment, do you mean the one in `Source Code Management` part or the one from `GitBucnet` part, I am using ssh protocol, the repository url from Source Code Management part is set as `ssh://git@localhost:29418/xxx/yyy.git`, and the url from GitBucket part is set as `http://localhost:1616/xxx/yyy`, when gitucket send a webhook for the project, the json's property `repository -> url` is `http://localhost:1616/xxx/yyy`. But still can't trigger build when push to gitbucket. Click `Build now` by hand, would succeed though.

Comment: @NaokiTakezoe I kind figured out the solution, need to use `http` instead of `ssh` to make it work, could check the answer I added below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(With the help in comment, and trying out, kind of figured out the mechanism and could built automatically via webhook now.)*

**Mechanism - Jenkins's `Gitbucket` plugin**

- The plugin determine which job to trigger by comparaing following 2 values:

  1. Jenkins job's `repository url` under `Source Code Management`.
  2. Gitbucket repo's git clone url of **http** protocol.

**Tips:**

- So **can't use ssh** protocol in jenkins job's `repository url` under `Source Code Management`.
  Because it won't match the url used by gitbucket's webhook, thus can't trigger build. Use http protocol instead.
- In jenkins's job, the `url` under `Gitbucket` section.
  It specify the home page url of the repo in gitbucket (*not for git clone*), it's mainly for link usage.
  It's optional, if set, then there will be a link to the url in the job's page.

Comment: Thanks for the summary!